# Is bypassing Drupal's #token protection against CSRF safe for search forms specifically?

Tags: 7, forms, security

I see that `$form['#token']` is employed in [drupal_prepare_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_prepare_form/7) and [drupal_validate_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_validate_form/7) as a protective measure against cross-site request forgery.

I am wondering about the necessity of this measure on site-search forms specifically, including core's search_box() and search_form() as well as a form built from scratch in a module that similarly implements a search by feeding arguments into a view.

I have seen it mentioned (in drupal_prepare_form(), in fact, and possibly other places I can't recall) that the search forms would be a viable case in which to work around the token protection. But then, why doesn't core do so by default?

(Note: I'm  not asking for help with code to work around it, as I've figured that part out already.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the biggest question when judging a potential CSRF problem is whether some form of damage will be done if a user is tricked into taking the action. If there is a CSRF vulnerability that deletes a user or unpublishes a node, that would be a problem. But being tricked into executing a search is only potentially a problem in terms of the resources a search takes to execute (which is not that much). Even if the core search doesn't bypass the token, it is accessible as a GET url (search/node/keyword) so someone could be tricked into visiting that URL bypassing the form in front.

Another way to think about it is whether the action is [idempotent](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html). A search is an idempotent action (by the W3 definition, log records might be created, but that's not a big deal), so it doesn't need CSRF protection.

Comment: Thanks for answering this.  Is the token protection on the core search just because Drupal protects all forms by default?

Comment: @MPD - yes, I believe that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to bring about reasons why you should never bypass #token: [CSRF: Avoid security holes in your Drupal forms.](http://pixeljets.com/blog/csrf-avoid-security-holes-your-drupal-forms)

And the specific instances you've provided don't seem to warrant bypassing #token.

Comment: The pixeljets article doesn't support your claim (and isn't a particularly great article, tbh). IMO it is totally appropriate to bypass CSRF in this instance.

Comment: Does #token reduce functionality in searches?  I think I'm starting to understand why it would be safe, but I still don't quite get what the benefit of bypassing #token is.

Comment: @JohnathanElmore, bypassing #token lets do AJAX login w/o needing to rebuilding search forms.

Comment: Had some link rot, new link is http://pixeljets.com/blog/csrf--avoid-security-holes-in-your-drupal-forms-/